# Flutter Pod Install Syntax Error "Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end"

Tags: ios, flutter

I am new in flutter. i got error when running pod install for flutter project.

Pod File :

```
 # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  http: 0.13.5
  intl: any
  lottie: 2.3.2
  provider: 6.0.5
  shared_preferences: 2.1.0
  flutter_svg: 2.0.5
  path_provider: 2.0.14
  permission_handler: 10.2.0
  image_picker: 0.8.7+4
  image_cropper: 3.0.3
  flutter_native_image: 0.0.6+1
  ffmpeg_kit_flutter: 5.1.0-LTS
  video_player: 2.6.1
  google_sign_in:
  firebase_core:
  firebase_auth:
  flutter_facebook_auth:
  shimmer_animation: 2.1.0
  device_info_plus: 9.0.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.6.2
  webview_flutter: 4.2.1
  flutter_switch: 0.3.2
  dotted_border: 2.0.0+1



  # Pods for Runner

end
```

Error :

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end
  http: 0.13.5
      ^
 unexpected fraction part after numeric literal
  http: 0.13.5
        ^~~~.

 #  from ios/Podfile:8
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    http: 0.13.5
 #    intl: any
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Thank You In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please read through https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html and follow their lead on syntax.

E.g. each dependency should look similar to `pod 'http', '0.13.5'`

Comment: this pod file auto generated for flutter i already check like this but show error dependancy not found error when i do like this.

Comment: Error [!] Unable to find a specification for `http (= 0.13.5)`